# Combobox not working with selection statement

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

My combobox is not working in the selections statement, the statement itself works if I enter the value I am after. I think there may be a problem with the combobox itself or can anyone see something wrong with my code?

```
Private Sub btnViewTimeTable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnViewTimeTable.Click

    If (cbDay.Text = "Monday" Or cbDay.Text = "Tuesday" Or cbDay.Text = "Wednesday" Or cbDay.Text = "Thursday" Or cbDay.Text = "Friday" Or cbDay.Text = "Saturday" Or cbDay.Text = "Sunday") Then
        Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT Time, Activity, Equipment FROM TimeTable WHERE Day = 'cbDay.text'"
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlQuery, conn)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Table")
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("Table")

        With DGTimeTable
            .AutoGenerateColumns = True
            .DataSource = ds
            .DataMember = "Table"
        End With

        With DGTimeTable
            .Columns(0).Width = 108
            .Columns(1).Width = 154
            .Columns(2).Width = 278
            Me.DGTimeTable.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
            Me.DGTimeTable.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
        End With

    Else
        MsgBox("Please Select a Day!")

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these initial lines

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT Time, Activity, Equipment " & _ 
                         "FROM TimeTable WHERE Day = ?"
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlQuery, conn)
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cbDay.text)
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "Table")
....
```

In your original code, you try to pass, between single quotes the name of the combo and its property text, but in this way the text is interpreted literraly, meaning that the database engine search a record where the column `Day` contains the string value `cboDay.text` not the actual value of the combobox text

There is also another problem. You are using `MS-Access` as database, so the words TIME and DAY are reserved keywords in `Jet-Sql` and it is not possible to use them as column names unless you enclose them in square brackets. If it is still possible, I suggest to change the name of these columns because you will have this annoying problem everytime you use this table.

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT [Time], Activity, Equipment " & _ 
                         "FROM TimeTable WHERE [Day] = ?"
```